# one-parameter groups

Tags: differential-geometry

Let TM the bundle tangent of a differential maninfold M 
Let φ: R × TM - → TM defined by φ (t, X) = e^tX. (i) Show that φ is a 1-parametric group of TM transformations. (ii) Calculate the vector field Y in TM associated with φ. (iii) Prove that Y is invariant under φ.
The first section is immediate, the second is where I have a problem because I am confused because the elements are vector fields and I have not found a way to apply the definition, someone knows some similar result or proceeds in the same way?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The vector field $V$ attached to $\phi(t,X)=e^tX$ is called the canonical vector field. It is described here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_tangent_bundle#Canonical_tensor_fields_on_the_tangent_bundle

Locally, the tangent bundle is trivial, for every $x\in M$ there exists $U$ an open subset containing $x$ such that the restriction of $TM$ to $U$ is isomorphic to $U\times\mathbb{R}^n$. $T(U\times \mathbb{R}^n)=TU\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V(x,X)=(0,X)$. You have ${d\over{dt}}_{t=0}\phi(t,x)={d\over{dt}}_{t=0}(x,e^tX)=(0,X)$ in the local coordinates